# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list',I need to split data from xpath(as list)into two

Tags: python, list, xpath

```
 published_date = r"published\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*at\s*(.+)\s*"
    raw_published_date = player.xpath('//div[@class="lpadding20"]/text()')
    subst = "published date = \\1\\npublished time = \\2"
    result = re.sub(raw_published_date,subst, 0, re.MULTILINE)

    if result:
            print (result)
```

I need to split the data from xpath into two

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should post at least a representative sample of `player` as well as an example of your desired output.

Comment: player= published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM"
published_date =6/11/2019

Comment: published_time=8:02am is the desierd output

Comment: xpath vl produce data's like published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM",it a list